# custom folder structure in sbt for scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

The default folder Structure of SBT is like this:

```
src
  - main
      - scala
  - test
      - scala
```

But I want to have a custom folder structure, something like this:

```
src
  - main
  - test
```

So my question is:

How can I customize my build.sbt file, to have a custom folder structure and have Intellij Idea recognize the new structure?

Comment: I would not recommend changing the default structure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why wouldn't you recommend that... I dont think, there is Something technical wrong with IT... Or is it?

Comment: First of all, any new member of the team would feel odd and would question the decision. Second, you may cause trouble with further tooling. Third, the day you may need to add resources or java classes or something else then you would need more setup. On the other hand, what did you win? avoid creating a folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html, you would need to apply the following in your build.sbt:

```
Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / "src/main"

Test / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / "src/test"
```

I have not tried this, so not sure if this works as expected nor how far Intellij Idea supports this (though I'd expect it to fully support this).